# Variable value after function multiple run

Tags: php, function, variables

I'm having an issue with a var value, that should increase everytime a function runs.

Illustrative code:

```
$i = 1;
function() {
     ...
     $i++;
}
```

This function is called on a page multiple times, and i need that $i value to be used on a lot of stuff inside it.

Thing is, $i value always ends up with the value equal to 1.

Any clues?

Thanks

Comment: Read up on how variable scope works. Variables declared outside a function are not automagically visible inside it.

Comment: Thanks DCoder, silly me. Declared the var global.

Answer (score 0):

The `$i` in the function is not the one you defined outside it.

Here's a resolution:

```
$i = 1;
function test(&$i) {
    $i++;
}

test($i);
```